# запуск php страницы каждые n секунд из js с передачей данных

Tags: javascript, php, get, таймер

есть задача, есть index.html в ней должен быть скрипт с циклом который прерывает цикл на несколько минут, а затем дальше продолжает.
на C# бы это было

```
for(....){
   //мой код
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

как бы это было в js?

и попутный вопрос:
в этом цикле должно запускаться файл "test.php?i=0&t=1"  (еще и передать в него данные из этого цикла) который лежит на том же сервере, который выполнится и цикл пойдет дальше

буду благодарен если кто то поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction(i, t) {
  // ajax to test.php
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: "test.php",
    data: { i: i, t: t },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("SUCCESS", data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("ERROR", xhr, status, error);
    }
  });
  setTimeout(myFunction, 5000, i, t);
}
```

Comment: а как послать эти i, t методом GET на php страницу?